# How can I get only some value in list?

Tags: python

```
import psutil
applist = list(psutil.process_iter())
for app in applist:
    print(app)
```

It's a script to get running Process in macOS, I got the list and it showed

```
psutil.Process(pid=12723, name='Google Chrome', status='running', started='13:54:23')
```

But I only want to get the 'Google Chrome' part, how can I do that? I want to use `split()`, but it said `'Process' object has no attribute 'split'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
import psutil
applist = list(psutil.process_iter())
for app in applist:
    print(app.name())
```

If you want to know more read [relevant `psutil.Process` docs piece](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#psutil.Process.name).